# No power off after shutdown

Tags: hp

I installed Ubuntu Studio 18.4 64 bit on an HP DC7800 PC.
If I select Shutdown the session closes but the PC stays powered on with the Ubuntu Studio logo on the screen till I press the power button.
Have I to do anything in the BIOS?
Regards
marius

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done so, you should try `systemctl poweroff` and see if that works.

Comment: It might also be worth checking ``/var/log/syslog`` for various ACPI and bios warnings.  Could be that your vendor bios is not playing nicely.  There will be warnings if that's the case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/999761)

Comment: With systemctl poweroff I had the same behavior...

Comment: Sorry @Pilot6.  I should have been more careful.  I intended to comment.  marius: did you look at your syslog?